# PHP create an empty array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$number_array = array();

//in a while loop

//part of code
if(array_key_exists($read_num, $number_array))
{
        $arr[$read_num][A] .= $new_A;
}
else
{
$inner_arr = array( "$read_num" => array( "id"=>$read_num, "A"=>$new_A ) );
$number_array = array_push($number_array,$inner_arr);

unset($inner_arr);
}
```

I get error like:

> Warning: array_key_exists() [function.array-key-exists]: The second argument should be either an array or an object in try.php on line 24
>   Warning: array_push() [function.array-push]: First argument should be an array in try.php on line 33

I declare an empty array outside of the while loop

```
$number_array = array();
```

what did i do wrong here that  cause the error to appear

**EDIT:**

I have this value when I did the code above

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0011] => Array
            (
                [id] => 0011
                [A] => 2.50
                [B] => 2.00
                [C] => 5.40
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0017] => Array
            (
                [id] => 0017
                [A] => 5.00
                [B] => 0.00
                [C] => 8.00
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0022] => Array
            (
                [id] => 0022
                [A] => 1.00
                [B] => 0.00
                [C] => 1.60
            )

    )
```

How do I remove the `[0]` , `[1]` and `[2]` and make it as `[0011]` , `[0017]`, `[0022]` so my array key exists can work

Comment: Don't make stealth edit's! If you changed your question or appended a new one please mark it with: `EDIT:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you re-assign the return value of `array_push` to `$number_array`

```
$number_array = array_push($number_array,$inner_arr);
```

remove it :

```
array_push($number_array,$inner_arr);
```

Because `array_push` return new number of elements in the array not the array itself.

Alternatively you can just write:

```
$number_array[] = $inner_arr;
```

It's the same thing.

Comment: Hi thanks for the solution, may I ask if I want to array_push index to a certain key e.g $number_array[$number] , how do I achieve it. because I tried array_push and it insert int sequence [0] > [1] then 2 etc..

Comment: @NormaHoliga then use the second option I gave you `$number_array[$index] = $inner_arr;`